# Getting IO privileges in Linux

Tags: linux, root, fedora, privileges

I have installed `flashrom` software. When i try to run `sudo flashrom` command it gives me "Could not get I/O privileges (Operation not permitted). You need to be root" error. Also I tried `su` command to switch root and run again. I also tried `sudo -i` command to login as root. However any of them did not work

Comment: why votedown instead of getting help?

Comment: Probably because it's offtopic (it should be on SU). But probably that person should have left a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#if defined (__OpenBSD__)
    msg_perr("If you are root already please set securelevel=-1 in /etc/rc.securelevel and\n"
         "reboot, or reboot into single user mode.\n");
#elif defined(__NetBSD__)
    msg_perr("If you are root already please reboot into single user mode or make sure\n"
         "that your kernel configuration has the option INSECURE enabled.\n");
#endif
```

Reading this from the FlashRom.org pastebin site should give some insight.

This is the only file in Flashrom that contains the line, "You must be root"
Therefore, in my opinion, this is the only place the error can be coming from.

Answer (score 1):

I changed secure boot option in bios settings as disabled. So I can run the flashrom program. But it gives this output.

> WARNING! You seem to be running flashrom on an unsupported laptop.
>   Laptops, notebooks and netbooks are difficult to support and we
>   recommend to use the vendor flashing utility. The embedded controller
>   (EC) in these machines often interacts badly with flashing. See the
>   manpage and http://www.flashrom.org/Laptops for details.
>
> If flash is shared with the EC, erase is guaranteed to brick your
>   laptop and write may brick your laptop. Read and probe may irritate
>   your EC and cause fan failure, backlight failure and sudden poweroff.
>   You have been warned.

So there is nothing to do. I have to search another tool to flash my bios